# how to show a dialog box inside of a thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

i'm trying to show a dialog box after something happend in my thread

i run this code on ui thread and a runtimeexception throws!!

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    dlgAlert.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.custom_dialog_values_new_high_score));
    dlgAlert.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.custom_dialog_values_new_high_score_title));

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dlgAlert.create();

    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.custom_dialog_values_yes_button_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
        {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);

    alertDialog.show();
```

the following exception is:
"Performing stop of activity that is not resumed"

what is the problem?

how can i resolve this?

EDIT:

my thread section is:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                                    // it's the function which called dialogbox
                gameIsFinish();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    });
```

Logcat exception:

```
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.foroutannezhad.colorname/com.foroutannezhad.colorname.MainActivity}
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.foroutannezhad.colorname/com.foroutannezhad.colorname.MainActivity}
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3133)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3220)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-05 10:30:02.643: E/ActivityThread(24497):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: please share the thread part also

Comment: Put your all code where you display this Dialog?

Comment: have you tried putting alertDialog.show() in runOnUiThread() ??

Comment: post all the exception

Comment: Use Handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: Please share your whole code of your Activity. There can be so many sources of errors, you can't expect help without giving the broader context of your problem. Have you forgot to invoke any super method? etc....

Answer (score 0):

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    dlgAlert.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.custom_dialog_values_new_high_score));
    dlgAlert.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.custom_dialog_values_new_high_score_title));

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dlgAlert.create();

    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.custom_dialog_values_yes_button_text), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
        {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);

    alertDialog.show();
});
```